# MNIST digit classification for digits only in the range [5,6,7,8,9]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write a simple code for classifying MNIST dataset but only for digits 5,6,7,8,9. I wrote the code below. Upon running, I get an accuracy of 0 and loss of nan. I tried to do the same with digits 0,1,2,3,4 and it runs perfectly with accuracy of almost 99.4% on the training data (just changed the train_mask and test_mask below to [0,1,2,3,4]). Can someone help me to understand why the code doesn't do anything for digit classifying in the range 5,6,7,8,9? Thanks for the help in advance!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

num_digits_to_classify = 5

train_mask59 = np.isin(y_train,[5,6,7,8,9])
test_mask59 = np.isin(y_test,[5,6,7,8,9])

x_train59, y_train59 = x_train[train_mask59], y_train[train_mask59]
x_test59, y_test59 = x_test[test_mask59], y_test[test_mask59]

# Reshaping the array to 4-dims so that it can work with the Keras API
x_train59 = x_train59.reshape(x_train59.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test59 = x_test59.reshape(x_test59.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
# Making sure that the values are float so that we can get decimal points after division
x_train59 = x_train59.astype('float32')
x_test59 = x_test59.astype('float32')
# Normalizing the RGB codes by dividing it to the max RGB value.
x_train59 /= 255
x_test59 /= 255


checkpoint_path = "D:/home/work/Fast_Learning/training/cp.ckpt59"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten()) # Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(num_digits_to_classify,activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model()

model.fit(x=x_train59,y=y_train59, epochs=20,callbacks = [cp_callback])
```

```py
Epoch 00019: saving model to D:/home/work/MNIST/training/cp.ckpt59
Epoch 20/20
29404/29404 [==============================] - 3s 109us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` the target labels are expected to be in the range `[0, num_digits_to_classify)`. When you select numbers 0 to 4 this is the case, but when you select 5 to 9 then they are offset by 5. Hence, before fitting, you should adjust the target labels:

```
y_train59 -= 5
y_test59 -= 5
```

By the way, if you're using the `tensorflow.keras` module like so:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
```

it should generate a corresponding error message (not sure if `keras` does that as well):

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).
```

### For an arbitrary number of elements

You have multiple options to fit only a subset of the MNIST digits 0-9:

1. Set the number of nodes in the last `Dense` layer to 10 (and just fit with fewer numbers),
2. Compress the actually used digits (e.g. `[0, 1, 5, 6, 8]`) into the range `[0, N)`.

For case 1)

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))  # last layer of model
```

For case 2)

```
# Transform y_train (and similarly y_test).
unique, index = np.unique(y_train, return_inverse=True)
y_train = np.arange(len(unique))[index]
# To get back the original labels, just index into the unique values.
unique[y_train]
```

Note that `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is for cases where your labels are integers and `categorical_crossentropy` is for cases where these labels are one-hot encoded. For example:

```
sparse_categorical_crossentropy: y = [0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0]
       categorical_crossentropy: y = [[1, 0, 0],
                                      [0, 0, 1],
                                      [0, 1, 0],
                                      [0, 1, 0],
                                      [0, 0, 1],
                                      [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried that and it works. However, I have another follow-up question. In the present case it is quite simple as you suggested to just subtract 5. I also tried with a general mask: say [0,1,5,6,8] and now I get accuracy of 0.1984 and loss = nan (see output below). Is there any way to make this more general? Is 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' the problem? I tried with 'categorical_crossentropy' and I get an error (wrt shape of array of last dense layer).

Epoch 20/20
29855/29855 [==============================] - 3s 99us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.1984

Comment: Error with 'categorical_crossentropy': 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_7 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (1,)
dense_7 is the last dense layer connecting to the 5 categories

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for a great explanation. I'll try out your solution.

Comment: @Shrini  i tried running the below                                                                                    # Transform y_train (and similarly y_test).
unique, index = np.unique(y_train, return_inverse=True)
y_train = np.arange(len(unique))[index]
# To get back the original labels, just index into the unique values.
unique[y_train]